# Is there a workaround for the known bug in dynamic EnumProperty?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, panel

So I was making an addon with a dynamic EnumProperty and apparently ran into a known bug when trying to use `Expand = True` for this property in the panel. Although everything works fine when not using `Expand = True`, for my addon, it is essential to have the options expanded and not collapsed in a drop-down menu. The bug can be found in the documentation:

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty

[image]

This is the most compact example I could think of (add a few objects to the scene to see the bug in effect):

```
import bpy

def getEnumStuff(self, context):
    return [((obj.name, obj.name, "")) for obj in bpy.context.selectable_objects]

class OBJECT_PT_example_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_category = "Example"
    bl_label = "Example"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, "stuff", expand = True)
        
classes = (
    OBJECT_PT_example_panel,)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.stuff = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "stuff", 
        items = getEnumStuff,
        description = "")

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I tried a lot of things, such as making the list global before returning it from the getEnumStuff function and copying the name strings in order to have them point to a different address than the original object names. Nothing I tried improved the results so far.

The question is, is there even a workaround for this bug? Is there another way to have the options expanded in the panel while still being able to select them (not only printing the name)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Warning in the documentation states the `EnumProperty` should have a permanent handle on the items.

> There is a known bug with using a callback, Python must keep a
> reference to the strings returned by the callback or Blender will
> misbehave or even crash.

One way I see, without resorting to a `global` variable, is to add an attribute to the `getEnumStuff` function. [See relevant PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/).

By the way, if you pass the `context` in a function, you should not use `bpy.context` afterwards but rather the `context` parameter because there could be a mismatch between the two, resulting in an incorrect context error.

**Important note :**

Enum items can be generated with a python generator using `(item1, item2, item3)` however this won't be cached as it is generated on the fly every-time. You **need** to use a python list `[item1, item2, item3]` to correctly serialize the result.

```
import bpy


def getEnumStuff(self, context):
    getEnumStuff.enum_stuffs = [((obj.name, obj.name, "")) for obj in context.selectable_objects]
    return getEnumStuff.enum_stuffs
getEnumStuff.enum_stuffs = []


class OBJECT_PT_example_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_category = "Example"
    bl_label = "Example"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, "stuff", expand = True)
        
        
classes = (
    OBJECT_PT_example_panel,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.stuff = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "stuff", 
        items = getEnumStuff,
        description = "")


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Note that the line `getEnumStuff(context) # Update enum items before drawing them` can be avoided, as this kind of "making sure" is error prone. In `def getEnumStuff(context):` add `return getEnumStuff.enum_stuffs` and in `def register:` change the lambda setup to `items = lambda self, context: getEnumStuff(context),`

Comment: @taiyo yeah I just realized by re-reading it that it was weirdly coded. Hopefully my python skills have improved a bit in the last two years >< Thank you.

Comment: i have just seen you took care of that after i added my comment^^ +1

Answer (score 3):

For an EnumProperty on a bpy.types.Object, I had text corruption with storing the `items` array in a global. A global string cache worked better for me.

```
STRING_CACHE = {}
def intern_enum_items(items):
    def intern_string(s):
        if not isinstance(s, str):
            return s
        global STRING_CACHE
        if s not in STRING_CACHE:
            STRING_CACHE[s] = s
        return STRING_CACHE[s]
    return [tuple(intern_string(s) for s in item) for item in items]


def getEnumStuff(self, context):
    # make your items like normal here
    items = ...

    # call intern_enum_items before you return
    return intern_enum_items(items)
```

The downside is the strings in `STRING_CACHE` will never be GCed (sort of the opposite of the original problem). For most people though, I doubt the cache will grow large enough for it to become an issue.