# Dynamic Enum Property Translation Problem

Tags: python, interface, properties

I have a problem with a dynamic enum. Strangely enough special characters are not handled there as you would imagine.

Here is a script to test. So that you don't have to create extra files, as it is the case with me, I just made a text file, where each line is an item for the enum property (So to test the script you need a text file with name text in the text editor, where the lines should contain special characters).

In the 3D window 2 enum properties are displayed under My Panel. The first enum shows special characters, the second enum, with the dynamic icons does not. I am completely at a loss. Can anyone help me?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty
                       
                       

def Enum_Items(self,context):
    
    EnumItems = [('1','Fluegel',''),('2','Nägel',''),('3','Mönch','')]
    
    return EnumItems

def Dynamic_Enum(self,context):
    
    EnumItems = []
    Index = 0
    
    for i in bpy.data.texts['Text'].lines:
        Index += 1
        EnumItems.append((str(Index),i.body,''))
    
    return EnumItems

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    my_enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator / Dropdown",
        description = "sample text",
        items = Enum_Items)
        
    Dynamic_Enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator_2 / Dropdown",
        description = "dynamic items",
        items = Dynamic_Enum)

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        mytool = context.scene.my_tool
        
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum")
        layout.prop(mytool, "Dynamic_Enum")

            
        return {'FINISHED'}
    

classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
        
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Enumator with a fixed list:

[image]

Enumarator with a dynamic list:

[image]

This is what the funny characters are supposed to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My problem was apparently related to this post here:
```

[Is there a workaround for the known bug in dynamic EnumProperty?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216230/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-known-bug-in-dynamic-enumproperty)

I could not see the connection between update and translation. But it works :)  I have adjusted my script like this:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import EnumProperty
                       
                       
def Enum_Items(self,context):
    
    EnumItems = [('1','Fluegel',''),('2','Nägel',''),('3','Mönch','')]
    
    return EnumItems

def Dynamic_Enum(context):
    
    Index = 0
    
#    Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = [((line.body, line.body, "")) for line in bpy.data.texts['Text'].lines]
    
    Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = []
    for line in bpy.data.texts['Text'].lines:
        Dynamic_Enum.enum_items.append((line.body, line.body,""))
    
#Dynamic_Enum.enum_items = [] 
    

class MyProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    my_enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator / Dropdown",
        description = "sample text",
        items = Enum_Items)
        
    Dynamic_Enum : EnumProperty(
        name = "Enumarator_2 / Dropdown",
        description = "dynamic items",
        items = lambda self, context: Dynamic_Enum.enum_items,
        )

class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        mytool = context.scene.my_tool
        Dynamic_Enum(context) # Update enum items before drawing them
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum",text="static")
        layout.prop(mytool, "Dynamic_Enum", text= "dynamic")

    

classes = [MyProperties, ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
        
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
#Props zugänglich machen
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
        
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```