# Garbage characters appeared in my Enum property

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I was making an addon which required a feature to select a material in an enum property. This is part of the code which I wrote to generate the enum property.

```
def GenerateProperty():
  def getMaterialList(self,context):
    _materials = []
    for i in range(0,len(bpy.data.materials)):
      mat = bpy.data.materials[i]
      _materials.append((str(i),mat.name,''))
    return _materials
  bpy.types.Scene.Materials = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Materials", items=getMaterialList)
```

The items of the enum is dynamically updated while each clicking event. The result ends up like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Everything works well until I add a material with Chinese characters. Now the enum property looks like this:

[image: Garbage characters appeared]

But my material slot displays these characters properly.

[image: Screenshot of the material slot]

I try to print `mat.name` in python console, and it displays correctly as well. I am now stuck and would appreciate any help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216230/is-there-a-workaround-for-the-known-bug-in-dynamic-enumproperty

Comment: @scurest so this seems to be a known bug in enum property? thanks so much for your reply!

Comment: Yup, especially for non latin characters

Comment: @Gorgious I tried again by creating a global _material list and manually update that list before "draw" function. That works, and garbage characters no longer appear anymore.

Comment: @Gorgious So it turns out that it's not a problem associated with decoding errors. It is actually a problem of the dynamic enum property.