# How to show limited enum items?

Tags: python

I want to show enums up to 5 items.

Is it possible?

[image]

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)
        
        # I want like this:
        if context.scene.enum_type == 'FIRST':
            col.prop(context.scene, 'enum', text='Enum 1-5', expand=True)
        elif context.scene.enum_type == 'LAST':
            col.prop(context.scene, 'enum', text='Enum 6-10', expand=True)


enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)


enum_items = (
    ('1', '1', ''),
    ('2', '2', ''),
    ('3', '3', ''),
    ('4', '4', ''),
    ('5', '5', ''),
    (None),
    ('6', '6', ''),
    ('7', '7', ''),
    ('8', '8', ''),
    ('9', '9', ''),
    ('10', '10', ''),
)
        


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=enum_items)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.enum
    del bpy.types.Scene.enum_type 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Is `items=enum_items[:5]` enough for you? Or do you want to show all enum items until `None` is encountered, wherever it may be placed in your tuple?

Comment: All enum items until `None`, I updated my code.

Comment: What does the `index` property do in `layout.prop()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this? But need some tweak/hack with UI

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)

        # I want like this:
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(text='')
        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.scale_x = 1.15
        col.use_property_split = False
        if context.scene.enum_type == 'FIRST':
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='1')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='2')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='3')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='4')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='5')            
        elif context.scene.enum_type == 'LAST':
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='6')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='7')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='8')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='9')
            col.prop_enum(context.scene, 'enums', value='10')

enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)

enum_items = (
    ('1', '1', ''),
    ('2', '2', ''),
    ('3', '3', ''),
    ('4', '4', ''),
    ('5', '5', ''),
    ('6', '6', ''),
    ('7', '7', ''),
    ('8', '8', ''),
    ('9', '9', ''),
    ('10', '10', ''),
)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    bpy.types.Scene.enums  = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=enum_items)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.enums
    del bpy.types.Scene.enum_type


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: It is useful for enum with fewer items, but not practical with lots of items. I have 45 items.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this answer answers your original question. You can't keep adding stuff to your question after someone takes their time to answer it. You should really consider stopping this behaviour mate. Cheers

Comment: @Gorgious, I already knew that solution. that is why I said it is not practical for lots of enum items. I don't want to hardcode all the enum items because the enum will grow in size later.

Comment: @Karan It doesn't matter what you already know or don't know if you don't write it in your question. Nobody can assume anything about what's not in your base question. Again, it would avoid wasting both your time and the time of several benevolent answerers in a lengthy back-and-forth.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit too much back-and-forth, I think this is what you're looking for. You'll need [dynamic enum items](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) :

[image]

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)
        text = 'Enum 1-5' if context.scene.enum_type == "FIRST" else 'Enum 6-10'
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum', text=text, expand=True)


enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)


def get_enum_items(self, context):
    get_enum_items.items.clear()
    if context.scene.enum_type == "FIRST":
        get_enum_items.items = [
            ('1', '1', ''),
            ('2', '2', ''),
            ('3', '3', ''),
            ('4', '4', ''),
            ('5', '5', ''),
        ]
    elif context.scene.enum_type == "LAST":
        get_enum_items.items = [
            ('6', '6', ''),
            ('7', '7', ''),
            ('8', '8', ''),
            ('9', '9', ''),
            ('10', '10', ''),
        ]
    return get_enum_items.items


get_enum_items.items = []


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=get_enum_items)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you're wondering about the weird `get_enum_items.items`, you can refer to the warning in the docs or [Is there a workaround for the known bug in dynamic EnumProperty?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/216230/86891)

Answer (score 1):

I edited your script to show only the wanted parts of your `enum_items`, depending on where the separator `(None)` is placed in your tuple.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_type', expand=True)

        # I want like this:
        if context.scene.enum_type == 'FIRST':
            col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_first', text='Enum 1-5', expand=True) # take first enum items
        elif context.scene.enum_type == 'LAST':
            col.prop(context.scene, 'enum_last', text='Enum 6-10', expand=True) # take last enum items

enum_type = (
    ('FIRST', 'First', ''),
    ('LAST', 'Last', ''),
)

enum_items = (
    ('1', '1', ''),
    ('2', '2', ''),
    ('3', '3', ''),
    ('4', '4', ''),
    ('5', '5', ''),
    (None),
    ('6', '6', ''),
    ('7', '7', ''),
    ('8', '8', ''),
    ('9', '9', ''),
    ('10', '10', ''),
)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    # create two enum items parts with None separator
    ni = enum_items.index(None)
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_first = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=enum_items[ : ni])
    bpy.types.Scene.enum_last  = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Enums', items=enum_items[ni+1 : ])

    bpy.types.Scene.enum_type = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name='Types', items=enum_type)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.enum
    del bpy.types.Scene.enum_type 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

I think the `index` property of `layout` will not help you here, as the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) say:

> index (int in [-2, inf], (optional)) – The index of this button, when
> set a **single** member of an array can be accessed, when set to -1 **all**
> array members are used

but you want **some** of your array.

Comment: I want to get enums from one `EnumProperty`

Comment: I dont think thats possible. Basically you have one enum property `enum_items` and just prepare it for presentation with helper enum properties. Any technical reason why you need to enforce only one enum property?

Comment: because my code depends on one `EnumProperty`, I can't make two `EnumProperty` it will break my script. I want to just show the items depending on another `EnumProperty` e.g. `enum_type`

Comment: Well, then show more surrounding code. I cant understand why the script breaks.

Comment: my code depends on `scene.enum` so I can't make two enums e.g. `scene.enum_first` and `scene.enum_last`

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this answer answers your original question. You can't keep adding stuff to your question after someone takes their time to answer it. You should really consider stopping this behaviour mate. Cheers