Dropdown enum not changing
I am trying to change a dropdown programatically. In some experiments that I have made, it changes in the terminal, but wont change in the UI.
I want to change the dropdown from showing "2" to showing "b".
Here is my code (taken mostly from Darkfall's video on dropdown menu)
import bpy
 
 
 
class ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Name of the Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Template Tab"

    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        layout.operator("wm.template_operator")
        
 
 
 
 
 
class ADDONAME_OT_TemplateOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Template Operator"
    bl_idname = "wm.template_operator"
    
    
    test_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name="",
    description="",
    items=[("1","2","3")]
    )
    
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    
    def draw(self, context):

        test_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name="",
            description="",
            items=[("a","b","c")]
            )
        
        print("it has entered into the draw command")

        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "test_enum")
        
    
    def execute(self, context):
        
        return {'FINISHED'}    
    

     
 
 
 
classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel, ADDONAME_OT_TemplateOperator]
 
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

If you have any advice on how to change the enum, I would be happy to hear it.
I've tried many different things, but none of them work. So I'll just leave this "Minimal Reproduceable Example" here showing what I want

You cannot directly modify the items list inside the draw method as you attempted. Instead, you can define a function that returns the items dynamically, which can then be used to assign new sets of options based on some conditions.
import bpy

class ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Name of the Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Template Tab"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("wm.template_operator")


def get_dynamic_enum_items(self, context):
    """Function to dynamically change enum options"""
    my_condition = True # Check any condition to switch options
    if my_condition:  
        return [("A", "Option A", "Option A description"), 
                ("B", "Option B", "Option B description")]
    else:
        return [("1", "Option 1", "Option 1 description"), 
                ("2", "Option 2", "Option 2 description")]


class ADDONAME_OT_TemplateOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Template Operator"
    bl_idname = "wm.template_operator"
    
    test_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Dynamic Options",
        description="Options based on some condition",
        items=get_dynamic_enum_items
    )

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    def draw(self, context):
        print("Entered the draw command")
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "test_enum")
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print(f"Selected option: {self.test_enum}")
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_TemplatePanel, ADDONAME_OT_TemplateOperator]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Aha! Thank you! It worked! I believe that I had already tried that but I must have messed something up. Thank you for clarifying.
Im thinking that I messed up the arguments for the secondary function "get_dynamic_enum_items" somehow. Once again, thank you!

@Zeno Note if you start seeing funny characters in your dropdown it's because you need to store the result in a variable. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/216230/86891
